# Customizing a Basic List of Figures Display

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, bold, small-caps

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

\newcommand\NewCaption[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{\scshape{#2 #1}}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageA Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-b}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageB Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: Is this List of Figures display customizable; and if so, how may I have the entire display appear in bold, as well as the captions themselves (ImageA Caption, ImageB Cation) appear in small caps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of figures is customizable! Perhaps someone more experienced than me can point to a package that has something fancy to do so, but in my opinion, the best way to do it is at the source!

The list of figures is actually defined by the document class you use! In your case, since you are using book as a document class, LaTeX calls the `book.cls` class at the base folder. There, in the line 662 you will find the following:

```latex
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

This line is the one that handles the format of the input to the list of figures. If you are curious on how this all work, you can check page 49 of its [original documentation](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/classes.pdf)!

For your particular case, just add these lines before starting the document:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{%         % Figure label command
  \scshape                          % Small caps
  \bfseries                         % Bold
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}  % Dotted line
}
\makeatother
```

What this does is to patch the original `\l@figure` command to add what you wanted. You can edit this as you want depending on what you need!

For this particular case, you should get something like this:

[image: Output1]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You already loaded package `caption`, so you can take advantage of its setting.

With `font={Large,bf,sc}` in `\captionsetup` (no need to repeat it for every figure), you can have a large, bold, small caps caption.

With

```
\captionsetup[figure]{
  position=below, aboveskip=10pt,
  }
```

you can set the position and the skip of the caption (no need to put `\vspace{10pt}`).

As for the List of Figure, package `tocloft` allows to customize it.
With `\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries}` you have bold figure title in LoF.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty, font={Large,bf,sc}} % needed only once
\captionsetup[figure]{
  position=below, aboveskip=10pt,
  }

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries} 
  
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{ImageA Caption}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{ImageB Caption}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\newpage\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]